# silex custom/persistant remember me

Tags: php, silex, remember-me

I want use the class PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices or my custom class for delivery the remember me token but I dont know how to configure it into Silex 2.

How can I do ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I know the default remember me configuration and work fine. But, I need custom this default behavior for implement more security check.

Comment: Have you tried following the [documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers/remember_me.html) or tried anything at all that you can add to the question?

Comment: Thanks, I know the default remember me configuration and work fine. But, I need custom this default behavior for implement more security check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not descibed in the documentation :

For load a custom remberme service, I have define the service manually with name :
"security.remember_me.service.".

Now I have my custom behavior.

Answer (score 1):

you can used  the RememberMeServiceProvider: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/remember_me.html

i hope this what you search about her :)

Comment: Thanks, I already use it. But The default behavior is too insecure in my context.
The default behavior store all information on user into the cookie. But I want store a key into the cookie and the username into my database.
I can reset all remembered information by flush the table into my database. This is only one use case wanted.

Comment: Now I'm realizing my graduation project with Silex and i new developer :p . 

but this if you want set your cookie : 
public function testSetCookie( $value)
{
    $cookie = new Cookie('key'', $value);
    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
}

public function testGetCookie(Request $request)
{
   $cookies = $request->cookies;

    if ($cookies->has('key'))
    {
        var_dump($cookies->get('key'));
    }
}